# Regex for git commit-msg hook

Tags: regex, git, hook, commit

I am trying to achieve following structure for git commit msg:

```
X=Uppercase character
Y=Number 0-9
category=fix, chore, doc, etc...

XXXXY-YYY [category] XXXXX*
```

this is my commit-msg file

```
MSG_FILE=$1
FILE_CONTENT="$(cat $MSG_FILE)"
# Initialize constants here
export REGEX="\D\D\D\D\d-\d\d\d \[(fix|poc|chore|feat|refactor|style|test)\] .*"
export ERROR_MSG="Commit message format must match regex \"${REGEX}\""
if [[ $FILE_CONTENT =~ $REGEX ]]; then
 echo "Nice commit!"
else
  echo "Bad commit \"$FILE_CONTENT\", check format."
 echo $ERROR_MSG
 exit 1
fi
exit 0
```

But all I get is:

```
    $ git commit -m "PBCL2-666 [fix] whatever"
Bad commit "PBCL2-666 [fix] whatever", check format.
Commit message format must match regex "\D\D\D\D\d-\d\d\d \[(fix|poc|chore|feat|refactor|style|test)\] .*"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `REGEX="[^0-9]{4}[0-9]-[0-9]{3} \[(fix|poc|chore|feat|refactor|style|test)].*"`. Make sure the engine that parses the pattern is not POSIX BRE.

Comment: @AD7six `\D` matches any non-digit char and OP used it, thus, all I am trying to say is that probably the engine used does not recognize the construct. If the bracket expression and the whole pattern in my suggestion works it means the engine is POSIX ERE and then I could answer the question. Now, there is too little information for an answer.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew How do I find out what parser is used?

Comment: Markus, now I see you are using it in Bash. You should not use `\D` and `\d` as POSIX ERE does not recognize it. Use `[0-9]` to match a digit (or `[[:digit:]]`) and `[^0-9]` (or `[^[:digit:]]`) to match a non-digit.

Comment: So, the pattern should be `REGEX="^[[:upper:]]{4}[0-9]-[0-9]{3} \[(fix|poc|chore|feat|refactor|style|test)] .*"`

Comment: Very nice, it works!
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the regex in Bash and thus using the POSIX ERE regex engine.

POSIX ERE does not recognize the `\D` construct matching any non-digit char. Use `[0-9]` to match a digit (or `[[:digit:]]`) and `[^0-9]` (or `[^[:digit:]]`) to match a non-digit.

However, you need `[[:upper:]]` to match any uppercase letter.

```
FILE_CONTENT="PBCL2-666 [fix] whatever"
# ....
ERROR_MSG="Commit message format must match regex \"${REGEX}\""
REGEX="^[[:upper:]]{4}[0-9]-[0-9]{3} \[(fix|poc|chore|feat|refactor|style|test)] .*"
if [[ $FILE_CONTENT =~ $REGEX ]]; then
 echo "Nice commit!"
else
  echo "Bad commit \"$FILE_CONTENT\", check format."
 echo $ERROR_MSG
 exit 1
fi
```

See the [online Bash demo](https://ideone.com/ySZJpm).

Note I added `^` at the start to make sure matching starts from the beginning of string only.